# Equivalence of maximisers

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Consider two unknowns $y\in \mathcal{Y}$ and $s\in \mathcal{S}$. Let $f$ be a function of $(y,s)$. Let $g$ be a function of $s$.

Consider the following problem
$$
\max_{y\in \mathcal{Y},s\in \mathcal{S}} f(y,s)-g(s)
$$
Suppose that the maximisers are unique and denote them by $(y^*,s^*)$.

Consider now the following problem
$$
\max_{y\in \mathcal{Y}} f(y,s^*)
$$
Again, suppose that the maximiser is unique.

Question: is it true that $argmax_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}f(y,s^*)=y^*$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

Suppose $y^* \neq \bar{y} \in \underset{y \in \mathcal{Y}}{\mathrm{arg\max}} \: f(y,s^*)$. Then we have by the optimality of $\bar{y}$: $$f(\bar{y},s^*) > f(y^*,s^*) \implies f(\bar{y},s^*) - g(s^*) > f(y^*,s^*) - g(s^*),$$ which contradicts the fact that $(y^*,s^*) \in \underset{(y,s) \in \mathcal{Y} \times \mathcal{S}}{\mathrm{arg\max}} \: f(y,s) - g(s)$.